# Create View in specified database with dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I am writting a dynamic sql to drop and create view in different database.

So I wrote:

```
set @CreateViewStatement = 
                '
                USE ['+ @DB +'];
                CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyTable]
                AS

                SELECT ........something
exec (@CreateViewStatement)
```

It gives me error:

> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

If I remove the USE DATABASE statement it works fine, but then the database is not specify anymore....

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use nested `EXEC` calls. The database context changed by the `USE` persists to the child batch.

```
DECLARE @DB SYSNAME

SET @DB = 'tempdb'

DECLARE @CreateViewStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @CreateViewStatement = '
      USE '+ QUOTENAME(@DB) +';
      EXEC(''
             CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyTable] AS
             SELECT 1 AS [Foo]
      '')

                          '
EXEC (@CreateViewStatement)
```

Comment: +1 - If you script out views using SMO this is how the framework does it as well - definitions are executed in dynamic SQL to get around the restriction

Comment: @KingChan - you can both upvote and accept, FYI ;)

Comment: @JNK +1 of course~ :)

Comment: definitely worked!! although i used it, wih many variables inside the nested query so i was a headache becuz of the quote handling! great solution though !

Comment: You are a hero. Will name my firstborn child after you.

Answer (score -1):

One way I have handled when run into this case is placing GO after use  statement.

```
set @CreateViewStatement = 
'
  USE ['+ @DB +']; GO
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyTable]
  AS

  SELECT ........something'
exec (@CreateViewStatement)
```

Comment: Just so you know, GO statment won't runs in exec

Comment: This won't work in the context of dynamic SQL. `GO` is a batch delimiter in the client tools not a TSQL keyword.